# ReactJS: Why different values from one state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm getting into Reactjs with very basic component.
I'm logging out the same state from different functions, but what I'm seeing is the different values.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Test = props => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log("count in interval is:", count);
      }, 1000);
  },[props]);

  function btnClick() {
    const newCount = count + 1;
    setCount(newCount);
    console.log("count changed to: ", newCount);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      count is {count}
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={btnClick}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Output after some clicks and wait, log is:

```
Test.js:8 count in interval is: 0
Test.js:15 count changed to:  1
Test.js:15 count changed to:  2
Test.js:15 count changed to:  3
Test.js:15 count changed to:  4
(8 rows) Test.js:8 count in interval is: 0
```

I expect the "count" to be the same in both functions.
Can any one explain this?

Thank so much.

Comment: useEffect() would only get triggered if the props have changed, not the count value. Try changing [props] to [count]

Comment: @rrd yeah, but I setup a interval in useEffect, which should run repeatedly.

Comment: I don't think that will work, it won't have access to the count variable within it's scope. It will trigger once when the FC loads because of [props]. Then the interval starts but only inside there, as useEffect itself will never be called again. I'd suggest removing the interval and putting the dependency as [count]

Comment: What is the point of setInterval? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The second argument of `useState` is asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test` only has one `setInterval` function where `count` is always `0`. Since it's only created during initial render.

It **never** had another `setInterval` created because the effect **never got triggered** with `[props]` as the dependency.

To have `setInterval`'s count change on every re-render:

- Remove the dependency
- Return a clean-up function inside the effect

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const t = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("count in interval is:", count);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(t); // cleanup on every re-render
  }
  // no dependency: effect runs on every re-render
);
```

**But the above code will have a warning:**

> "*missing `count` dependency*"

So simply add `count` as dependency to **only run the effect** when `count` changes.

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const t = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("count in interval is:", count);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(t); // cleanup "old" setInterval
  }
  , [count] // ony run effect every time count changes
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `count` doesn't change, this is the expected behavior, though not an obvious one.

See, you even declare `count` as a `const count`, it is immutable. What is happening instead is that during the first render `count` gets assigned value of `0`. The value of `count` never changes, what happens instead is that component `Test` is called each time you change the state, and function `useState` assigns different values to the constant `count`, which is new constant every time.

So during the first render the value of `const count` gets captured by [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) inside your function that is called by `setInterval` and the value stays `0` forever.